# How can I email a group from Inbox?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I would like to send an email to a group from my Contacts by just typing the group name (as you can do in Gmail).

Is this possible in Inbox by Google?

Answer (score 0):

At this time it's not a built-in feature.

If you are using Inbox by Gmail in Chrome you could use a Chrome extension like [Insert Text](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/insert-text/abmgjcmmphkhndoahbfanhbgeekconmm?hl=en-US). This extension allows to store frequently used text fragments and make them available through the contextual menu by doing right click, in this case, on the TO, CC or BCC fields in inbox.

One caveat of this extension is that the text fragments are stored locally.

---

**References**

- [Compose a new email - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067585?hl=en)